# Laurent series expansion of function $f(z) =\frac{z^2+1}{z(z-3)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I am given the problem to calculate the Laurent series expansion fo $f(z) = \frac{z^2+1}{z(z-3)}$ in the regions $0<|z|<3$ and $3<|z|< \infty$. My question is around what center should I do the Laurent expansion?

Comment: What does the set of points $z$ with $0<|z|<3$ look like geometrically? Where is its center?

Comment: It's just an annulus centerd at 0, so should expando with respecto the center of the annuli always?

Comment: Yes. The shape of the region of convergence is determined by its center. And its size is the largest annulus with the given center where the function remains holomorpic.

Answer (score 0):

For $0<|z|<3$, we find the expansion around $z=0$ as

$$\begin{align}
\frac{z^2+1}{z(z-3)}&=-\frac13(z+z^{-1})\left(\frac{1}{1-z/3}\right)\\\\
&=-\frac13(z+z^{-1})\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^{n}}{3^{n}}\\\\
&=-\frac13\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^{n+1}}{3^{n}}-\frac13\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^{n-1}}{3^{n}}\\\\
&=-\frac{1}{3z}-\frac19-\frac{10}{9}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{z}{3}\right)^{n+1}
\end{align}$$

---

For $|z|>3$, we can facilitate our finding the expansion around $z=3$ by introducing a new variable $w=z-3$ and expanding around $w=0$.  Proceeding, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\frac{z^2+1}{z(z-3)}&=((w+3)^2+1)\left(\frac{1}{w(w+3)}\right)\\\\
&=\frac13(w+6+10w^{-1})\left(\frac{1}{1+w/3}\right)\\\\
&=\frac13(w+6+10w^{-1})\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-w)^{n}}{3^{n}}\\\\
&=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{-w}{3}\right)^{n+1}+2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{-w}{3}\right)^{n}-\frac{10}{9}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{-w}{3}\right)^{n-1}\\\\
&=\frac{10}{3(z-3)}+\frac89-\frac19\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{-(z-3)}{3}\right)^{n+1}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Urpi, please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  -Mark